# Get all form arrays to JS array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm having problem to get all form array values to JS array, with one value it working fine:

```
          var el = document.getElementsByName('p[]');
          for (var i = 0, j = el.length; i < j; i++) {
          var elem = el[i];
          alert(elem.value);
          }
```

But when I try to add more its not working:

```
var el = document.getElementsByName('p[]', 'k[]', 'ka[]', 's[]');
              for (var i = 0, j = el.length; i < j; i++) {
              var elem = el[i];
                      alert(elem.value);
                    $.post("test.php", { 'p': [elem.value] });
                      }
```

Here is my form: form is dynamic (with button click I can add new line with these 4 fields:

```
   <form name="form">
    <input type="text" name="p[]" id=name" />
    <input type="text" name="k[]" id="quant" size="3" />
    <input type="text" name="ka[]" id="price" size="10" />
    <input type="text" name="s[]" id="sum" size="10" disabled="disabled"/><br />
    </form>
```

Comment: [document.getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName) supports only one argument.

Comment: Why do your text inputs have array names?

Comment: Since you want to get all elements in the form, you can also use `var el = document.forms['form'].elements;`.

Comment: @Bergi because I as I mentioned when I click add button there adds same 4 input fields

Comment: @RobW does that actually work? I'm not seeing it in on MDC anywhere: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element#Properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`document.getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByName) doesn't magically take multiple arguments in the way that you're trying to use it. You need to call `gEBN` multiple times, once for each name (described in more detail by [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11421870/139010)).

Alternately, just loop over the `<form>`'s inputs:

```
var form = document.getElementsByName('form')[0];
var inputs = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0, j = inputs.length; i < j; i++) {
    // snip
}
```

Comment: You forgot to use only the first form from the NodeList.

Comment: @Matt Ball Now its working fine, is there a way also add field name like p=value, k=value... I vant this all data to send to php file and add it to mysql.

Comment: @OsvaldaKazlaučiūnaitė if you don't mind using jQuery, [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) will do all this work for you.

Answer (score 1):

The method get elementsByName takes one string argument, so you should do something like this:

```
var listOfElements = ['p[]', 'k[]', 'ka[]', 's[]'];
for (var i=0; i<listOfElements.length; i++) {
   var el = document.getElementsByName(listOfElements[i]);
   ...
}
```